# Increment float in React, string conversion, state representation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

Here is the critical logic of my codebase:

```
  addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
    let equation = this.state.equation
    console.log(parseFloat(equation))

    if(newLogic==="10%"){
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.10)
      console.log(newEquation)
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }else if (newLogic==="15%"){
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.15)
      console.log(newEquation)
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }else if (newLogic==="20%"){
      let newEquation = Number(equation) + (Number(equation) * 0.20)
      console.log(newEquation)
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }
    else{
      // we're adding more numbers
      let newEquation = equation + newLogic
      this.setState({equation: Number(newEquation).toFixed(2)})
    }

  }
```

For some reason I can't understand, if I enter three consecutive `6`'s, I get this output:

[image]

As opposed to `666`, which is what I want in fact. What is a solution to this?

I've tried to use `parseFloat()`, as you can see- but it had seemingly no effect.

---

Example of `this.state.equation`:

[image]

**EDIT:**

[image]

[image]

**EDIT II:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class ButtonNumber extends Component {
  render() {
    const { number, addLogicToEquation, evalEquation } = this.props
    const numberClass = " btn btn-number-" + number

    //maybe you should put a big switch statement here
    //turning those into numbers?

    let inputNumber = Number(0)

    switch (number) {
        case number === "0":
            inputNumber = Number(0)
        case number === "1":
            inputNumber = Number(1)
        case number === "2":
            inputNumber = Number(2)
        case number === "3":
            inputNumber = Number(3)            
        case number === "4":
            inputNumber = Number(4)            
        case number === "5":
            inputNumber = Number(5)            
        case number === "6":
            inputNumber = Number(6)
        case number === "7":
            inputNumber = Number(7)            
        case number === "8":
            inputNumber = Number(8)            
        case number === "9":
            inputNumber = Number(9) 
    }           

    return (
      <button className={numberClass} onClick={() => {addLogicToEquation(number)}}>
        {number}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample output of `this.state.equation`? That way I have something to work with in my terminal.

Comment: it looks like that when I just keep hitting `5`s

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to ask what does `this.state.equation` look like before you start performing operations on it? What does it look like at the very top?

Comment: Looks like this `this.state = { equation: "", }`

Comment: the full codebase is [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The key difference for my code is I use type coercion to ensure the numbers are strings and concated. Also, I have a different set of logic for your percentage. It doesn't really need to be a huge conditional. Also, I have renamed variables. Your variable names are really deceptive. You're create new calculation values, not equations

```
addLogicToEquation(newLogic) {
  let newValue, multiplier
  let equation = this.state.equation
  if (newLogic.includes("%")) {
    multiplier = parseFloat(newLogic.replace("%","")) / 100.0
    newValue = parseFloat(equation) + parseFloat(equation) * multiplier 
  } else {
    newValue = parseFloat('' + parseFloat(equation) + newLogic)
  }
  this.setState({equation: newValue.toFixed(2)})
}
```

Comment: so- it definetly looks much more beautiful- but the error is still the same as before

Comment: By error do you mean `NaN`? Throw a debugger into that function and make super-extra-sure your argument, `newLogic` you're passing in is what you're expecting.

Comment: no no, for instance, if I enter `5` for five separate times, it will be like this in the image I just added to the OP, and then- strangely enough- in this other way for `6`...

Comment: @s.matthew.english updated. I changed it to `newValue = parseFloat('' + parseFloat(equation) + newLogic)`. Does that work?

Comment: @s.matthew.english I'm quite convinced your issue is not with this function. I'm testing it myself and it works perfectly fine. When you `console.log(this.state.equation)` you are absolutely positive you're getting what you expect? `console.log(newLogic)` as well.

Comment: maybe you're right- I tried to modify the file [ButtonNumber.js](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc/blob/master/src/ButtonNumber.js), as you see in **EDIT II** but that also just resulted in `NaN`

Comment: ok so- I fixed it- the thing was- I had to construct it with `0` instead of `""`, but now I get this strange thing- where the value doesn't sum- it just accumulates... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj4eq.png

Comment: wait- never mind- that;'s the functionality I want- because it's a calculator- aha- so- works! :) thanks!!!

Comment: That's something I probably should've seen.. Well, I'm glad you ultimately got it fixed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is when you enter second `6` you concatenate "6.00" string value to "6". So it becomes "6.006" and `toFixed(2)` round it to 6.01. To avoid this remove ".00" part when you concatenate.

```
let newEquation = Number(equation) + newLogic;
```

Comment: man I tried that- but then I think I also have to take it away again before I look at it later- when I see the value for the second, third, forth time- so I'll always have to keep converting back and forth between the two representations -isn't it? and also - I need to keep the value of the decimal place- so I can't just get rid of it often, you know what I mean?

Comment: No. I tried that in your code base and it works nicely.

Comment: The problem is in 38 line in App.js. Replace that line with this.

Comment: it doesn't add up the sum

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: the input is numbers from the app- it's got a keyboard- they're working as buttons, [it's all here on my GitHub](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc)

Comment: I mean when you enter what numbers or percentages you get the output in the image you posted.

Comment: ok yeah- now i get what you mean- I think that happens [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc/blob/master/src/ButtonNumberContainer.js) and also [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/rehackt-calc/blob/master/src/ButtonNumber.js)